# Regex which satisfies 3 separate cases

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, regex-group

I'm trying to figure out a regex which can be used with java's String.split(regex) in order to get an array of "lines" from a file.

A carriage return does not define the end of a line, instead a comma does - however not all commas. If a comma is between parentheses, single quotes or a comment (/* comment, more comment */) it does not signify the end of a line.

Example:

```
1 test fixed(5,2),
  2 another_test char(12),
  2 a_third_test,
    3 one pic'9{9}V.99',
    3 two pic'9,999V.99',
    3 three fixed(7,2),
  /* test,t*/
  /*test 2,*/
  /*and more */
  2 another_field fixed bin(13),
  2 a_really_long_super_long_field_name_requiring_two_lines_for_declaration
    char(1),
  2 a_field char(8);
```

The output expected is (with \t and extra white spaces omitted for clarity):

```
1 test fixed(5,2)
2 another_test char(12)
2 a_third_test
3 one pic'9{9}V.99'
3 two pic'9,999V.99'
3 three fixed(7,2)
/* test,t*//*test 2,*//*and more */  2 another_field fixed bin(13)
2 a_really_long_super_long_field_name_requiring_two_lines_for_declaration
    char(1)
2 a_field char(8)
```

I've come up with 3 separate regex expressions to get the 3 pieces:

- `,(?![^(]*\))` - all commas not in parentheses
- `(,(?![^']*'))` - all commas not in single quotes
- `(,(?![^\/\*]*\*\/))` - all commas not in a comment

I've tried joining them with an or `(.*?)|(,)|'.*?'|(,)|\/*.*?*\/|(,)` but get the following:

```
1 test fixed
2 another_test char
2 a_third_test
3 one pic
3 two pic
3 three fixed
2 another_field fixed bin
2 a_really_long_super_long_field_name_requiring_a_line_break_...        char
2 a_field char
```

Is there a way where these 3 regex expressions (or is there a better one?) can be combined to find the groups that satisfy all 3?

UPDATE:

I can accomplish the exact thing with some simple java, but I'd like to do so with regex as an academic persuit.

```
String temp = "";
for(String line:text.split("\n")){
  if(line.trim().charAt(line.trim().length()-1) == ',' || line.trim().charAt(line.trim().length()-1) == ';'){
    System.out.println(temp + line);
    temp = "";
  } else {
    temp += line.trim();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this where the or operator might help?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, using \(.*?\)|(,)|'.*?'|(,)|\/\*.*?\*\/|(,)
I get:

`1 test fixed
    2 another_test char
    2 a_third_test
    3 one pic
    3 two pic
    3 three fixed
    2 another_field fixed bin
    2 a_really_long_super_long_field_name_requiring_two_lines...        char
    2 a_field char`

Comment: That's the sort of thing that ought to be in the body of the question.

Comment: Are the commas always at the end of the line?

Comment: Yes, with the exception of a comment.
A line ends when there is a comma that is not between single quotes or parentheses.

The files I'm trying to parse are actually old PLi and COBOL structures.A line declaring a field will always end with a comma except at the end of the structure which ends with a semicolon.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a cobol parser? Like [Koopa](https://sourceforge.net/projects/koopa/) for instance

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Koopa looks like a cool tool for COBAL (which we do have some of), but it looks like it doesn't handle PLi code too well and that's the bulk of what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be over thinking this a little bit. It's important to keep in mind that regular expressions are made for parsing [regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). When you need to check if you're inside a comment or parens or whatever else to know what a comma means, what you're looking at is a [context-sensitive language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar) (see diagram below).

[image: By J. Finkelstein (Own work) [CC BY-SA 3.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)], via Wikimedia Commons]

> By J. Finkelstein (Own work) [CC BY-SA 3.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)

That being said, matching commas and semi-colons at the end of a line is easy enough. `/\s*(.*?)[,;]$/gsm` works for the test input in your question. However, this doesn't take into account something like

```
test fixed(5,2),
/* a,
   multi-line,
   comment,
*/
```

The best option to get around this in my opinion would be to discard comments before you start parsing with `\/\*.*?\*\/`. If you need to keep the comments, you could probably use negative lookarounds but those are very inefficient and you would be better off writing a tokenizer/parser.

Comment: I was able to get the broken into the individual comma delimited lines with some simple java, and the use regex to  get the individual pieces from there. Thanks!